# Trays library button not catching mouse events in ogre 14.1

Tags: c++, game-development, ogre

I am developing using Ogre14.1 in Windows for making a clickable button in my project.
I follow the  official ogre documentation link is give below.
[https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/latest/trays.html](https://%20https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/latest/trays.html)

here is my entire Application code

```
class MyApplication : public ApplicationContext, public InputListener {
    

public:
    ShaderGenerator* shadergen = nullptr;

MyTrayListener mlistener; //see next code
SceneManager* scnMgr = nullptr;
SceneNode* LightNode = nullptr;
SceneNode* CameraNode = nullptr;
Viewport* viewport = nullptr;
void run() {
    // Main loop
    playing = true;
    while (playing) {
        getRoot()->renderOneFrame();
    }
}

void setup() override {
    ApplicationContext::setup();
    Root* root = getRoot();

    // Get the scene manager
    scnMgr = root->createSceneManager();

    // Register the input listeners
    addInputListener(this);

    // Create and set up the scene
    createScene(); //adding lights, cameras, etc
    addModels(); //added some models
    
    scnMgr->addRenderQueueListener(getOverlaySystem());
}

void loadResources() override
{
    addUI(); // ADDED TRAY BUTTONS
}

bool frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt) override
{
    mTrayMgr->frameRendered(evt);
    return ApplicationContext::frameRenderingQueued(evt);
}

void addUI() {
    cout << "creating UI" << endl;
 
    OgreBites::TrayManager* mTrayMgr = new OgreBites::TrayManager("InterfaceName", getRenderWindow(), &mlistener);
    mTrayMgr->setListener(&mlistener);
    mTrayMgr->showCursor();
    mTrayMgr->showTrays();
    mTrayMgr->showFrameStats(TL_BOTTOMLEFT, -1);

    Button* b = mTrayMgr->createButton(TL_TOPLEFT,"MyButton", "OK!", 50.0f);
 
}

};
```

and here is my TrayListener implementation

```
class MyTrayListener : public OgreBites::TrayListener {
public:
    void buttonHit(OgreBites::Button* button) override {
        cout << "buttonHit"; //not printed, function not getting called
        if (button->getName() == "MyButton") {
            // Handle button click event here
            button->setCaption("Clicked!");
        }

    }
};
```

It was not giving any errors but buttonHit() function was not triggered.

Edit 1:
As understood in comments, I have moved mlistener to class scope:

```
class MyApplication : public ApplicationContext, public InputListener {
    public:
        ShaderGenerator* shadergen = nullptr;
        SceneManager* scnMgr = nullptr;
        MyTrayListener mlistener; // <-----------------
        ...
}
```

Edit2:
I was wrongly creating TrayManager from setup(), instead of of loadResources() so fixed that. But now TrayManager constructor is throwing exception that file not found at the following line:

```
mCursor = (Ogre::OverlayContainer*)om.createOverlayElementFromTemplate("SdkTrays/Cursor", "Panel", nameBase + "Cursor");
```

I have already added "SdkTrays.zip" inside resources.cfg file.

Comment: I am not familiar with this framework, but can it be that you register your `MyTrayListener mlistener;` , and then in the end of `void addUI` this object goes out of scope, leaving your tray manager with a dangling pointer?

Comment: `{... MyTrayListener mlistener; ...; mTrayMgr->setListener(&mlistener); ...}` -- Basic C++ says that this cannot work, as `mlistener` is a local variable, and as soon as `addUI` returns, that local variable has gone out-of-scope.  So what will `mTrayMgr` be listening to?

Comment: I have understood and  edited my code but still not working

Answer (score 0):

The parent class ApplicationContext loads all resources from resources.cfg in its loadResources(); We didnt override it.

```
void loadResources() override
{
    ApplicationContext::loadResources();
    addUI(); // ADDED TRAY BUTTONS
}
```